# How can i serialize a FileStream in c#?

Tags: c#, serialization, filestream

i hope this is not a repeated question.
I've a class like this :

```
    [Serializable]
    class MyClass
    {
       int type;
       List <FileStream> listfile;
       string content_text;
       public MyClass(int t)
    {
        type = t;
    }

       public MyClass()
    {
           type = 0;
    }       
    }
```

i need to send an object of Myclass in a Socket with the method Socket.Send(byte []).
So i've to serialize this object. But also if i add [Serializable], FileStream isn't serializable, and i get an exception runtime.
Someone can help me ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What exception you get?

Comment: A stream represents an arbitrary length collection of bytes. You could possibly serialize it as an array of bytes, but it possible that it may not actually fit in memory if the file is very large. You're better off creating a protocol to transfer the contents using a series of buffer transfers of fixed size and store it as a file on the other end which can be opened and read as a stream there.  If it is sufficiently small to transfer as an object, then consider a better representation of its contents.

Comment: What is the purpose of sending a list of FileStream objects? you will need to open the file anyway. just keep a list of the properties of the file (path, FileMode...) instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you add Serializable to a class it doesn't change anything, it simply just tells the CLR that your class can be serialized.

Beacuse of this, any classes that are part of an object and are not by default Serializable will not get changed in anyway, and as such will cause the exception you see when you attempt to.

The following link will show you the MSDN documentation for the Serializable attribute : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

You can however mark individual properties in your class as not serializable by using the 'NonSerializedAttribute' as follows:

```
[Serializable]
class MyClass
{
  int type;

  [NonSerialized]
  List<FileStream> listfile;

  string content_text;
  public MyClass(int t)
  {
    type = t;
  }

  public MyClass()
  {
    type = 0;
  }
}
```

This will prevent the exception occurring, BUT it will do so by removing the actual property from the serialized output, which means if your wanting to pass the filestream objects over your socket, then your fresh out of luck unfortunately because your just not going to be able to.

Now, that said, you can attempt to read the contents of the file stream(s) into byte arrays, and you could then easily send those byte arrays as 'byte[]' is serializable without any issues.

I would however recommend that if your going to start sending byte[] arrays of arbitrary length over a socket, that you look at using a binary streaming protocol (Perhaps Google Proto Buffers) rather than the default text serialized objects you get out of the box.

Comment: Thank you all!
I'll try to put the content of my FileStream in a byte array, and send this.